# jQuery function on hover does not work, why is that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show description on picture while you hover on pic. The function does not work, I'm trying to use jQuery. I have other function that work, they can cause problem each other ? The other one use completely different classes and ids.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box').hover(function() {
        $('#details').show(500);
    })
})
```

```css
.box .details p {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-2 box" id="box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details" id="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to display the paragraph within the div (`#details p` instead of just `#detail`), since that's what's hidden in the first place.

Edited with 2 boxes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.details p').show(500);
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');
  })
})
```

```css
.box .details p {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: none;
}

.highlighted {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-2 box">
  <div class="imgBox">
    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 box">
  <div class="imgBox">
    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When i have 12 elements and when i hover on one i want to display only this one description, how can i do this ? Do i need to do 12 functions ?

Comment: @Buszek Check my edit, you can use `$(this)` combined with `.find()` to show the corresponding box. Note that you cannot use IDs in that case.

Comment: Cool that works fine. Another question, when i want to add background to both img and text on hover should i use .addClass() on details and box ? On class would be background.

Comment: @Buszek Just on the box itself (`$(this)`) since it contains everything. See my edit. Please create another question if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

A word about `hover()`

> Calling `$( selector ).hover( handlerIn,handlerOut)` is shorthand for:
>   `$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut )`;

so you need two handlers in `hover()` and you are only using one. add an handler for mouseleave. i.e:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box').hover(function() {
        $('#details').show(500);
    }, function() {
        $('#details').hide(500);
    })
})
```

for more read about hover() https://api.jquery.com/hover/

if you just want to show on mouseenter use `mouseenter()` 
https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Answer (score 0):

It is working, but you're trying to show a `div` that is already visible. I think you're trying to show the `<p>`. Use `$('#details p').show(500)` in the code as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box').hover(function() {
        $('#details p').show(500);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the details div on image hover, but the p inside is still hidden. Move display: none from p to .box .details.